# Symfony4: How to toggle entities using dotenv and multiple Entity Manager?

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

How it is possible through dotenv select different entity path with same name of entities.

Originally, We had application in Symfony 3 for people meetings on events of our organization. Then we decided to offer this application to our partners.

One of the partners asked us to customize the application for them with their data and specifications. We basically created a new instance of Symfony application with copy of database tables (with different prefix), changes in Entities to reflect new db table names, and some translation text changes.

It seems that other partners will follow this trend of customized instances.

Therefore, I am trying to update core application to Symfony 4 and I am trying to use multiple Entity Managers and dotenv to differentiate between partners database tables, as described bellow.

In a nutshell, I am trying to use multiple Entity Manager to switch db table names by prefix.

.env

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=oci8://user:pass@127.0.0.1:1521/XE
EM_TYPE=OpenAccess
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Only in security.yaml working env good

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\%env(EM_TYPE)%\Osoba:

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\%env(EM_TYPE)%\Osoba
                property: username
```

When i tried get %env(EM_TYPE)% in default_entity_manager, then give error **You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.%env(EM_TYPE)%_entity_manager".**  doctrine.yaml

```
parameters:
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: '%env(EM_TYPE)%'
        connections:
            MeetingTool:
                driver: 'oci8'
                charset:  UTF8

                schema_filter: /^MT_/
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            OpenAccess:
                driver: 'oci8'
                charset:  UTF8
                schema_filter: /^OA6_/
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        default_entity_manager: '%env(EM_TYPE)%'
        entity_managers:
            MeetingTool:
                connection: MeetingTool
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/MeetingTool'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\MeetingTool'
                        alias: App2
            OpenAccess:
                connection: OpenAccess
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/OpenAccess'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\OpenAccess'
                        alias: OpenAccess
```

and biggest problem is **use**, how i targeting right entity here?  for example loginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Entity\OpenAccess\LogPrihlaseni;
//use App\Entity\MeetingTool\LogPrihlaseni;

class LoginController extends AbstractController {

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

   public function logPrihlaseni() {
        $log = new LogPrihlaseni();
```

Comment: check the `.ccrm` file if the service is public or not

Comment: I don't understand comment. When I used text 'OpenAccess' or 'MeetingTool' in correct order in use statment or default_entity_manager choise everithing work fine. But i need choice in one place (ideal in .env) - controlling load correct entity.